# Java - get text of selected JTable header

Tags: java, jtable

So, JTable has some headers ... (with rowsorters) ...

- I want : text of header which has been clicked
- I do **NOT** want : name of selected column (lets pretend, we dont click on cells just on headers)

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 3):

okay, I solved it ...
Been messing with it for long time, then I created this thread and then I luckily found solution, so now I look pretty stupid :/

anywaay solution is here : 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/343480/Swing-AWT-SWT-JFace/java/JTableHeader-column-selection